# NHibernate Has Many Relationship with Grandchild Table Containing Multiple Many-to-One References

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, has-many, automapping

there are three existing tables defined like the following:

```
create table business_units (id number(10,0) not null, ... , primary key (id))
create table categories (id number(10,0) not null, ... , primary key (id))
create table paragraphs (
    id number(10,0) not null,
    business_unit_fk number(10,0),
    category_fk number(10,0),
    ...,
    primary key (id)
)
```

the entities are defined like:

```
public class BusinessUnit : Entity {
    public virtual IList<Category> Categories { get; protected set; }
}

public class Category : Entity {
    public virtual IList<Paragraph> Paragraphs { get; protected set; }
}

public class Paragraph : Entity {
    public virtual BusinessUnit Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

i have tried the following overrides:

`BusinessUnit` auto-mapping override:

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Categories)
    .Table("pp_paragraphs")
    .KeyColumn("business_unit_fk")
    .Inverse();
```

`Category` auto-mapping override:

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Categories)
    .Inverse();
```

i have has-many and many-to-one conventions that take care of the column names, so i don't think i need to specify here (or at least i don't think so). The auto-mapper takes care of the many-to-one reference for `Paragraph`.

the has-many mapping for `BusinessUnit` does not work. how can i pull this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use HasManyToMany here